# glunproject cheaper alternative

Tags: opengl, 3d, geometry, openframeworks, projection-matrix

I'm building a game in openframeworks where a camera moves over a stationary 2d plane in 3d space. I need to pick 5 coordinates for every frame as the camera is always moving (1 for the mouse and 4 for the corners of the viewport to workout what to draw). However I've found the gluUnproject function too slow. As I'm only picking coordinates on a stationary plane, currently on Z = 0, I figure I should be able to work out my coordinates pretty cheaply by using the modelview and projection matrices from my camera class but I just can't work out how to do the math.

To summarise, I have

Camera - MODELVIEW and PROJECTION matrices, VIEWPORT
Plane aligned to z-axis with dimensions world_dims.x, world_dims.y

I want to transform screen coordinates into unprojected coordinates on the plane without using gluUnproject.

Incase I'm being dumb with my gluUnproject heres the code for that bit

```
ofVec3f ofxGrabCam::pickCoordinate(ofVec2f t_mouseP) {
//read z value from depth buffer at mouse coords

ofVec3f t_mouseW(t_mouseP.x, t_mouseP.y, 0);

glReadPixels(t_mouseW.x, ofGetScreenHeight()-1-t_mouseP.y, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &t_mouseW.z);

if (t_mouseW.z == 1.0f){
    return ofVec3f(-99,-99,-99); //represents point not found
}

GLdouble c[3];

gluUnProject(t_mouseW.x, ofGetScreenHeight()-1-t_mouseW.y, t_mouseW.z, matM, matP, viewport, c, c+1, c+2);

ofVec3f mouseW(c[0],c[1],c[2]);

return mouseW;
```

}

Answer (score 3):

> However I've found the gluUnproject function too slow.

Backtransforming just 5 coordinates should not be a performance bottleneck.

> I want to transform screen coordinates into unprojected coordinates on the plane without using gluUnproject.

You have to determine the inverse transformation path. That is: inverting the matrices describing the way from model space to view space, (and at some point inverting the perspective divide) then passing into your coordinates into it. However, this is exactly what gluUnproject does.

Comment: I'm definitely getting a drop off in performance (trying to run at 60fps). Pretty sure I'm doing everything right but I'll edit some of my code into my question just incase. I've now been looking into this method http://www.mvps.org/directx/articles/rayproj.htm but still not having luck. Could you or someone give me the specific inversions I need to do in the specific order ?

Comment: I just wanted to say that I too have found gluUnproject to be a major bottleneck and would have loved if this question had an answer for an alternative.

Comment: @Jeff: The performance drop is not due to gluUnProject. The bottleneck is glReadPixels. If all you want is a ray, don't use glReadPixels and use 0 and 1 as Z coordinates.

Comment: My application is different than the one described in this question. What I am looking for is simply the distance from the camera for each pixel. glReadPixels is not the bottleneck, it's gluUnproject. I found a solution though of doing the transform myself following this code: http://olivers.posterous.com/linear-depth-in-glsl-for-real. It runs 7 times faster than gluUnproject (and I haven't even done it using a shader). I use glReadPixels for both.

Comment: @Jeff: Well in that case, if you pass on the order of 1 million pixels through gluUnProject, this will be of course slow. Read my original answer: "Backtransforming just 5 coordinates" **five**, not a million. I just skimmed over that article it linked, but it looks to me like this calculates the perpendicular distance parallel to the view axis, which may not exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Mine is a different question than what this asked. For my application the solution on that link is perfect